# Reusing an html template for multiple webpages at a time with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-side, client-side

A few months ago, I started a website. My problem is that I am starting to get a lot of pretty much what are just duplicate pages. I copy the raw HTML for my homepage and then get rid of everything that is very specific to my homepage, and that is only so I can use my same header and navigation menus. All of my pages have a lot of code in common. It is getting really tedious to redo this for each page. I know people have had this problem before, and I'm sure that there is some big secret (to me) API that everybody already knows about for doing this. But as I am approaching 50 pages, what I need is a basic HTML template page (which I can make) and then some javascript just to print that code out into one of my other pages. So if I want to add another item to my menu, I don't have to go through and change all 50 HTML pages, I can just change the template, and then that will be mushed into every other page. Maybe there is a server-side solution for this too. And feel free to mention that. But I am really good with javascript and not so good at server-side stuff. I really don't want this to affect my page load times (which I am very proud of and have worked very hard on). So maybe server-side is the solution for me. But If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it very much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'But I am really good with javascript' ==> Are you sure? Have you taken a look at using a framework like Vue? If you want to use PHP, have you looked into php include?

Answer (score 2):

you mean all the pages you have right now are static?

if yes, don't do it.
if you generate all the pages in that way after a while you can't expand your website easily and gods forbid if you wanna change a small design then you have to do it in all pages.

for dynamic pages you only design the page once and you load the parts that change with JS or PHP.

you need 3 things:

1- HTML Template of a page

2- Data base (SQL or NOSQL)

3- a backend language to communicate with the database and load the data for you based on the url that user enters. this can be anything from php to python

4(optional) to make your website mobile friendly and possible to work with by low speed internet, get the data with js and load it to the page partially.

if you ask my opinion, php laravel is really good that takes care of a lot of things for you. and for the js part you can use Vuejs.

have a good day!

Comment: You do not need a database to achieve this.

Comment: So is that most likely similar to say the way youtube does it, where every video's page is the same but the actual video is different?

Comment: A database on the backend is not necessary, but it makes it easier to keep track of the moving parts. In contrast to putting all the plumbing to handle the specific parts by managing the includes in the php file. You just need to query the db for a list of the files needed for a particular page.